Are claims not only restricted to the embodiments of the specifications?
I've heard that in some foreign countries,
if you file based on a provisional application that do not have claims,
then those countries will restrict you to only the embodiments of the specifications.
Can someone elaborate on the "restrict you to only the embodiments of the specifications" bit?
Questions:

I thought that the claims are by default indeed restricted to the embodiments disclosed in the specifications.
If this is not the case, what does it mean to claim an embodiment that is not in the specifications? Can you also give example?



I thought that the claims are by default indeed restricted to the embodiments disclosed in the specifications.

This would make patents fairly useless, since one can't predict and enumerate all possible variations of an invention. The purpose of the patent system is to provide a healthy incentive for innovation. Accordingly, one is allowed to have claims that are more general than the specific embodiments described. Indeed, leaving anything out of the claim amounts to a generalization. Furthermore one can sometimes recite generalized limitations that can be supported by multiple different embodiments.
That being said, if one uses means-plus-function language in the claim, that language is indeed limited to the corresponding bits of disclosure that define how the function is accomplished.

If this is not the case, what does it mean to claim an embodiment that is not in the specifications?

One can draft a claim based on a specific embodiment, but one does not claim an embodiment directly. Typically, if an embodiment has been described thoroughly enough that enablement cannot be questioned, it will also contain too much detail to make a useful claim.
The standards for the extent to which an embodiment can be generalized into a useful and valid claim after the initial filing varies across patent jurisdictions. IIRC, U.S. is more lax in this regard than, e.g., EPO.

So embodiments in the specifications should be detailed, while the claims should generalize the embodiments?
